# VBA code to paste value to an indexed position from a match on different sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am struggling for days to make this excel formula work from a command button.

```
=IF(‘Machine Status’!E$28=(INDEX('Import Pool'!$A:$H,MATCH(‘Machine Status’!$B$23,'Import Pool'!$G:$G,1),2))
```

then cut value from `‘Machine Status’!E$21,` and paste it in the indexed position column 8 next line

```
INDEX('Import Pool'!$A:$H,MATCH(‘Machine Status’!$B$23,'Import Pool'!$G:$G,1),8),"")
```

Comment: Do you just want it to change one cell when you click on the button?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Sorry it took me so long to see it.

Comment: What I really need to accomplish is complete code for a double click function on 400 cells that does the following.
Sheets are:
Machine Status
Tooling
Log
Audit
Dbl-Click cells are:
Sheet-(Machine Status) columns D, G, J, M, N, M, P, S, V ,Y, AB, AE, AH, and so on.
Rows-31 to 50 in each column
Data ranges for each column above are in 
Sheet-(Tooling), 20-row increments starting with:
91-110 for D,
111-130 for G
131-150  for J
and so on.
For the example here, we’ll use:
(Machine Status) P31:P50
to retrieve data from
(Tooling) rows 91-110
Dbl-Clk - (Machine Status) P31

Comment: Dbl-Clk - (Machine Status) P31
Copy value from:
Sheet (Tooling) F91
Paste value to:
Sheet (Tooling) G91
Subtract value in (Tooling) L91
from (Tooling) K91
Copy Row (Tooling) Row 91
Paste Row to (Log) in next available row with Date /Time in column A
Thank you, you guys are awesome